# How to trace 'Navigation triggered outside Angular zone' to origin, it it's possible

Tags: angular, ngzone, angular-ngzone

My Angular 11 application triggers this warning in console:

`Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?                      core.js:27937`

Is there a way to trace that warning to the point in my code that might be raising it (assuming the origin is really in my code)?

Comment: Are you using third-party libraries that make API calls such as Google Maps/social networks/payment ?

Comment: Not really. I'm using only [adal-angular4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular4) for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by console. If you're using Jest and its outputting that message to the console, you can use jest-fail-on-console to have the warnings give you better error messages:

https://github.com/ValentinH/jest-fail-on-console#readme

```
failOnConsole({
  shouldFailOnWarn: true,
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Not using jest. I guess it was a quirk from that version, because it disappeared when I upgraded to Angular 12.